# How to get the data from the BroadcastReceiver to another class BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am using the BroadcastReceiver in my application ,here i am receiving the current location and place in this class.hence i am getting the current location,hence my question is how to send this location string from this class to another class .i have to load this string data in the listview in another class so how can do this please help thanks in advance.                        My code is

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener {
    MyTrip trip_method;
    double latitude, longitude;
    Context context;
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        trip_method = new MyTrip();

        this.context = context;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Find_location();
        // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void Find_location() {
        // Location nwLocation;
        try {
            location = getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            System.out.println("nwLocation-------" + location);
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                System.out.println("latitude-------" + latitude + "longitude-----" + longitude);

                Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Mobile Location (NW): \nLatitude: " + latitude
                            + "\nLongitude: " + longitude,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // To display the current address in the UI
                (new GetAddressTask()).execute(location);
            } else {
                trip_method.showSettingsAlert("NETWORK");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Location getLocation(String provider) {
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                    MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                return location;
            }
        }
        return null;
    } 
    /* *//**//*
     * Following is a subclass of AsyncTask which has been used to get
     * address corresponding to the given latitude & longitude.
     *//**//**/
    private class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, String> {

        Context mContext;

        /* public GetAddressTask(Context context) {
            super();
            mContext = context;
        }*/


        /* *//**//*
         * When the task finishes, onPostExecute() displays the address.
         *//**//**/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String address) {
            // Display the current address in the UI

            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    "address---" + address,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Location... params) {

            String Address = null;
            String Location = null;
            Geocoder geocoder;
            List<android.location.Address> addresses;
            geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                Address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + ", " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + ", " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                Location = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                System.out.println("Location----" + Location);
               //This "Location" value i have to send to another activity
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Return the text
            return Address;
           /* } else {
                return "No address found";
            }*/
        }
    }// AsyncTask class
}
```

Comment: You can save the string in Shared Preferences and then use them where ever you want.

Comment: thanks for your reply,but i am viewing this location every 5min so i have to get this location value in another BroadcastReceiver which was in another class please help me

Comment: I am not understanding you, You have a string variable in one class and you need to access the same string in another class, am I right?

Comment: Yes, but while in ordinary method I am unable to view the string

Comment: ordinary method means?

Comment: address_method(Location),here by using this string i have to add this in this listview but i cant it shows nullpointer Exception

Comment: Yes it shows Null pointer because Location is null

Comment: How but in the toast message, it shows the location ,my dout is how i can get this to another broadcastreceiver where i have created in another claas

Comment: now i have to mark the path in map using this lat and log position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your code as appropriate:

In your First class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, another_activity.class);
intent.putExtra("Location", Location.toString);
startService(intent)
```

In your Second class:

```
 String Location = getActivity().getIntent.getStringExtra("Location")
```

Now you have passed string from one class to another. Use the Location variable where you need it.

Comment: but this class was called by a service its a background task so i cant put this intent

Comment: In this i am sending the location like this Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN").putExtra("Location", location);  context.sendBroadcast(intent); In the main activtiy onResume i have given this codings   IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.travelroutesapp"); location_received = new BroadcastReceiver() {@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {msg_for_me = intent.getStringExtra("location"); }  }; receiver this.registerReceiver(location_received, intentFilter); }

Comment: No its not working but I got this string by referring this example  http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/android-broadcast-receivers-a-tutorial.html.   But thanks for Your Help

Comment: Look at the edit, broadcast receiver is a service so change start activity to startService in my code and try this may work.

Comment: i have got the output by using the local broadcaster thanks for help

Comment: now by using this lat and long position i have to mark the current location in the mapview how can i do it

Comment: Since that is a different question can you please post that as a different question. Since every one will see you will get better answers. Please don mind.